# summarizing the contents of a text file to an other one using awk

Tags: awk

I have a big text file with 2 tab separated fields. as you see in the small example every 2 lines have a number in common. I want to summarize my text file in this way. 
1- look for the lines that have the number in common and sum up the second column of those lines.

small example:

```
ENST00000054666.6   2
ENST00000054666.6_2 15
ENST00000054668.5   4
ENST00000054668.5_2 10
ENST00000054950.3   0
ENST00000054950.3_2 4
```

expected output:

```
ENST00000054666.6   17
ENST00000054668.5   14
ENST00000054950.3   4
```

as you see the difference is in both columns. in the 1st column there is only one repeat of each common and without `"_2"` and in the 2nd column the values is sum up of both lines (which have common number in input file).

I tried this code but does not return what I want:

```
awk -F '\t' '{ col2 = $2, $2=col2; print }' OFS='\t' input.txt > output.txt
```

do you know how to fix it?

Comment: try to select a answer(after sometime of all answers) as correct answer too, so that thread could be considered as completed, keep learning and keep enjoying sharing knowledge, cheers.

Answer (score 3):

***Solution 1st:*** Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '{sub(/_.*/,"",$1)} {a[$1]+=$NF} END{for(i in a){print i,a[i]}}'   Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** In case your Input_file is sorted by 1st field then following may help you.

```
awk '{sub(/_.*/,"",$1)} prev!=$1 && prev{print prev,val;val=""} {val+=$NF;prev=$1} END{if(val){print prev,val}}'  Input_file
```

Use `> output.txt` at the end of the above codes in case you need the output in a output file too.

Answer (score 3):

If order is not a concern, below may also help :

```
awk -v FS="\t|_" '{count[$1]+=$NF}
                 END{for(i in count){printf "%s\t%s%s",i,count[i],ORS;}}' file
ENST00000054668.5   14
ENST00000054950.3   4
ENST00000054666.6   17
```

**Edit :**
If the order of the output does matter, below approach using a flag helps :

```
$ awk -v FS="\t|_" '{count[$1]+=$NF;++i;
                     if(i==2){printf "%s\t%s%s",$1,count[$1],ORS;i=0}}' file

ENST00000054666.6   17
ENST00000054668.5   14
ENST00000054950.3   4
```

Comment: @JamesBrown Thanks pal, I overlooked that fact.